# PHP download blocks rest of requests

Tags: php, session, locking, download

I am downloading files from my server using a very simple script:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($fichero));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

It works fine, but while the browser is downloading the file I cannot browse through the site or downloads other files from the same server. I have to wait until it finishes. It happens in Chrome & Firefox and I have also used other methods to download files with PHP, but with all of them I have this problem...so I suppose it's a problem in the server??

Thank you very much in advance :)

Comment: What happens when you try to browse other pages/download other files? Do you get an HTTP error (e.g. 403, 404) or does the connection just hang?

Comment: The browser tried to load the new page requested until the previous file was completely downloaded.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the server to me, what server are you using? Either it is configured to only accept one concurrent request from each host, or each request procedure blocks all execution of the server until the request is complete - far more likely to be the former, unless this is some completely non-standard server designed for tiny environments like routers, and even they don't usually suffer that problem. EDIT: Sorry, just saw that the sessions solution below was the answer, ignore me :-)

Answer (score 16):

This is because you are using PHP sessions, and while a session for one user is opened in one request, the same session cannot be opened in an other request.

Do a session_write_close() before readfile().

Comment: Great! I had solved a similar problem: when running long CURLs requests the rest of the site was unresponsive!