# Apache freeze when try to download a file?

Tags: php, apache, file, download

When I am trying to download a music file from http://timmytheterror.com/home/music_detail/233

login with username: amar  password: 123456 the start downloading but the apache stop processing other request. I cannot go to other pages until the download finished. My coding to download is

$path = base64_decode($path);
$id = base64_decode($id);

```
        $file_path= "http://timmy-the-terror.s3.amazonaws.com/".$path;

        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path."\""); 
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Location: $file_path");
    readfile($file_path);
```

and I open it in separate window but still parent window stop responding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP download blocks rest of requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077635/php-download-blocks-rest-of-requests)

Comment: I just answered it. I didn't look for previous posts +1 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding session_write_close(); to the download script. It will stop further writing to your session and allow other scripts/pages that use the session to continue.

```
session_write_close();
$file_path= "http://timmy-the-terror.s3.amazonaws.com/".$path;

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$path."\""); 
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Location: $file_path");
readfile($file_path);
```