# Apache becomes unresponsive during php curl_multi

Tags: php, apache, curl

I'm trying to use multiple thread curl requests in my application.
The problem is that during curl_multi requests the application becomes unresponsive (another requests to it just waiting). Moreover, no one can use the site during curl_multi. After the curl finishes the server answers just normal.

Comment: Given that PHP is not an interactive language, I can't figure what kind of responsiveness you're expecting to get. (Also, are you sure your code has nothing to do with whatever your issue is?)

Comment: I'm revising multiple items on eBay with php and curl_multi. I have very large amount of items and I wrote a status bar that connects to the database and returns me how much items remaining for revising. But the problem is that server don't answer untill curl is done.

Comment: That's how server-side languages work... only after the first command finish it will continue to the next one

Comment: @user2202635 How are you creating threads? Are you using experimental library [`pthreads`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pthreads.php)? Or are you simply creating another php process?

Comment: A "status bar" is not a standard PHP component. Sorry but we cannot read your mind.

Comment: It's another request (ajax) from the browser.

Comment: The status bar is implemented by me in JS.

Comment: I'm using curl_multi not pthreads.

Comment: @user2202635 You understand how http works, right? when client (in this case your script) sends request to server, server executes everything on its side, prepares output and sends back to client.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I'm creating another request to the application to get status data and it's another server script.

Comment: This is a very hypothetical question - can you show some code that you suspect is the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 4):

This is not related to curl_multi, but instead to PHP sessions.

You do two requests:

1. One that does curl requests, which last long
2. And a second request.

The first request opens a php session and locks it. Then it does the curl requests, which take some time.

The second request waits for the php session to be released, i.e. it waits until the first request finishes.

Any other request also waits for the php session to be released, and this is why it looks like the *application* is unesponsive.

The solutions are:

- avoid long-running scripts
- or close the session before long-running scripts, by calling session_write_close()

See [PHP download blocks rest of requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7077635/php-download-blocks-rest-of-requests/7077692#7077692)